# Overleaf: Disable spellchecking in \citep commands

Tags: overleaf

this is an Overleaf specific question.

When using \cite commands, the citation reference code (eg. `\cite{astley1987never}`) is very sensibly not spell checked, as it contains proper nouns and abbreviations a lot of the time. However, as soon as this is changed to the more specific Natbib commands `\citep` or `\citet`the spell checking re-activates and you get misleading red underlining suggesting a spelling error.

Is there a way to manually deactivate the spell checking for a certain command or can Overleaf handle this case somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = canada]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

Comment: I'm aware there are bugs around this such as https://github.com/overleaf/spelling/issues/3 but that's from 7 years ago and seems to have been forgotten about since the move to a monorepo

Comment: Hi Jess, Tom from Overleaf here. First, let me mention that this probably isn't well suited for StackExchange as a question (but I'm not much active here these days, so I'll leave that to others). Second, considering the issues, we had things like this _dormant_ for a while for some technical blockers. We're actively working on editor improvements now and this is on our list. If you wanna check the improvements already put in Beta testing, you can join our Beta program via https://www.overleaf.com/beta/participate -- I hope this helps!

Comment: Btw, you made us laugh in the Overleaf team with the "mini-Rickroll", as someone put it :-)

Comment: @yo' I'm glad you spotted that haha, thanks for the feedback. I've joined the beta and will fill out the feedback form, the ability to split the PDF output into a different window is already a great feature